# android sim pin unlock programmatically

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, sim-card

I have made an App (in android 2.3.6) that runs automatically at boot and doesn't allow users any use of the phone except for my app. To make this work I have changed the default launcher with my app, and blocked any hardware button and forced full screen. Everything works great but the problem is that I need to unlock the sim card inserting the pin code programmatically (the user must not be aware of it). I need to keep the pin code active in the sim because I can't allow the user to use the sim in other devices.
Is there a way to let my app unlock the sim card inserting the pin code programmatically?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018692/is-it-possible-to-unlock-the-sim-and-let-the-software-put-in-the-pincode?